# Copy all directories, with additional intermediate directory

Tags: maven, resources, maven-3

I have the following resources structure:

```
resources
    v1
        foo
        bar
    v2
        baz
```

and I want to copy these resources to another directory, but each version nested into another directory specified by a maven property, say `module-1`, e.g.

```
destination
    v1
        module-1
            foo
            bar
    v2
        module-1
            baz
```

This is so another module can add its own versioned files. In source control the directory structure is `module > versions`, but the destination requires them to be `version > modules`.

My current solution is to put the current into another maven property and use that in a normal resource plugin:

```
<properties>
    <patch>v3</patch>
    <module>module-1</module>
</properties>
<!-- ... further down below in the build-region ... -->
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-versioned-files</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${somedir}/destination/${patch}/${module}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/patches/${patch}</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

but this requires the property to be adjusted for each version, which is cumbersome and error-prone.
I just want the files for all versions to be properly copied.

Comment: Can please more in detail explain what those directories do and why they needed to be copied?

Comment: It's a business requirement. They are database migrations for my case, and the consuming software needs them in the described structure